# hudson plugin: add mutli-user functionality?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Is there a hudson plugin to add multi-user functionality ?

Users can create new account and run their own remote tasks.
Users can stop, delete, kill their tasks.

Also, is there a way to control what the user sees ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-user functionality is included in Hudson by default. See the following article for details: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Standard+Security+Setup